# How to delete aws s3 bucket in aws cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I have the ff s3 bucket, see image below:
[image]

I know how to delete them on the page but how can i delete them using aws cli?

I tried using

> aws s3api delete-objects --bucket
>   elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-613285248276

but it wont work.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use 'rb' option

E.g. `aws s3 rb s3://elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-613285248276`

For more details  [click here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rb.html)

If the bucket is not empty then use the `--force` flag

Comment: i tried this **aws s3 rm s3://elasticbeanstalk-ap-southeast-1-613285248276** but when i aws s3 ls again, it didnt delete my bucket.

Comment: Sorry. I posted the wrong command initially.. I've corrected that now

Comment: aws s3 rb s3://bucket/ worked on the other bucket but i got an error msg. of **remove_bucket failed: s3://elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-613285248276 An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the DeleteBucket operation: Access Denied** on my other bucket. I also checked the documentation you provided.

Comment: That sounds like permission issue

Comment: Yes, i think so. Thanks!

Comment: Found the answer to the access denied problem. I just deleted the bucket policy and successfully removed it.

Answer (score 2):

I am deleting S3 bucket from following command without any extra hustle of emptying it first

```
aws s3 rb s3://<BUCKATE-NAME> --force
```

for example

```
aws s3 rb s3://alok.guha.myversioningbucket --force
```

PS : Make sure you have programmatic access with policy "AmazonS3FullAccess"

Answer (score 1):

The following commands deletes the Bucket from S3

```
aws s3api delete-bucket --bucket "your-bucket-name" --region "your-region".
```